# Querying a df using its index based on values of another index Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, and I want to create a filtered df_1 based on the timestamp index of df_2, shown below. For each index value of df_2, I want to take all the rows of df_1 that is within timedelta of 1 day of df_2 index value.

Example: for df_2 index value `10/15/2017`, I want to include in the new df_outcome, all the rows of df_1 that are between `10/14/2017` to `10/16/2017`, which returns `10/14/2017  f` and `10/15/2017  g`. Any duplicates from the query are removed.

```
df_1    
Index   Values
10/2/2017   a
10/4/2017   b
10/5/2017   c
10/7/2017   d
10/9/2017   e
10/14/2017  f
10/15/2017  g
10/20/2017  h


df_2    
Index   Values
10/4/2017   Apple
10/6/2017   Banana
10/13/2017  Pear
10/15/2017  Pineapple


df_outcome  
Index   Values
10/4/2017   b
10/5/2017   c
10/7/2017   d
10/14/2017  f
10/15/2017  g
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I edited to change the index to timestamps, to reflect the actual problem. I'm so sorry for any confusion I did not anticipate it would be a problem. The timestamps are uneven.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to updated question

The new answer is based on the orignal one while using sets to identify valid indices:

```
# convert strings to timestamps if not done already
df_1.index = pd.to_datetime(df_1.index)
df_2.index = pd.to_datetime(df_2.index)

# helper function to extract days since epoch
def extract_days_since_epoch(timeseries):
    epoch_start = pd.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
    return (timeseries - epoch_start).days

# get indices as days
index_1_days = extract_days_since_epoch(df_1.index)
index_2_days = extract_days_since_epoch(df_2.index)

threshold = 1
ranges = [range(x-threshold, x+threshold+1) for x in index_2_days]
allowed_indices = {value for sub_range in ranges 
                         for value in sub_range}

# get intersection of allowed and present indicies
valid_indices = allowed_indices.intersection(index_1_days)

# use assign, query and drop to filter matches
df_1.assign(days=index_1_days)\
    .query("days in @valid_indices")\
    .drop(["days"], axis=1) 

            Values
Index   
2017-10-04  b
2017-10-05  c
2017-10-07  d
2017-10-14  f
2017-10-15  g
```

### Answer to original question

You can use pandas `Index`'s set operations for this purpose. First, create a set of allowed indices using list and [set comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Second, get the [intersection](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) of allowed and present indices. Last, use the valid indices to [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) your target dataframe.:

```
# define threshold range to include values from df2
threshold = 10

# create set of allowed indices via set comprehension
ranges = [range(x-threshold, x+threshold+1) for x in df_2.index]
allowed_indices = {value for sub_range in ranges for value in sub_range}

# get intersection of allowed and present indicies
valid_indices = df_1.index.intersection(allowed_indices)

# use reindex with valid indices
df_result = df_1.reindex(valid_indices)

print(df_result)

    Values
10  a
20  b
30  c
40  d
70  g
80  h
```

Comment: Thanks, what if the indices were timestamps? When I try your method I get 'Timestamp' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @A1122 Well, that's a different requirement. You have to either convert Timestamps to integers (seconds or whatever unit you need) or use `pd.Timedelta` as the range threshold. However, using the second approach, you will need to ensure that all timestamps share the same frequency.

Comment: I'm going to try the first approach you mentioned

Comment: Thank you. Side question - instead of seconds since epoch, is there a way to extract for microseconds/nanoseconds?

Comment: @A1122 To get nanoseconds, you can use `(timeseries - epoch_start).astype(np.int64)` within the `extract_days_since_epoch` function.

Comment: Hey @pansen, can you tell me what `allowed_indices = {value for sub_range in ranges for value in sub_range}` does? It seems to not work for me as I get memoryError using fake data that range has only 2 elements.

Comment: @A1122 I just tested my code snippet with your input data and it works fine. Please check your code again. To answer your question: `{value for sub_range in ranges for value in sub_range}` is a set comprehension which extracts all values from `ranges`. Because `ranges` is a list of iterables, we have to loop twice to extract the atomic values. It is just like a list comprehension without having duplicated values as a result and gaining efficient set operations like intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The following indexer should do the trick on datetimes:

```
threshold = pd.Timedelta('1 hour')

indexer = pd.Series(df1.index, index=df1.index).apply(
  lambda x: min(abs(x - df2.index)) < threshold
)

df1.loc[indexer]
```

Note: It doesn't scale well. It starts to take seconds if `len(df1) * len(df2)` ~ 10<sup>6</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to make it faster? My dataset is quite huge